# XCode 4.2.1: Undo operation is not working properly

Tags: xcode4, undo-redo

Anyone have the problem with Undo operation (Cmd + Z) in Xcode?
When I am edit my Objective-C code with Undo operation, some symbols are not correctly edited.
For instance:
was { 
with Undo {{ 

XCode 4.2.1

Comment: This has been happening to me as well. Whenever I delete and then overwrite a call, then cmd+z it, it mixes and matches the call.

Answer (score 4):

I have Xcode 4.3.2, which still has severe problems with undo/redo -- it will usually crash after one or two redo! Just before it crashes, it will usually do some nonsense edit.

---

*Added*:

I have experimented with the tip by Walt to turn off line numbers. However, I have not seen any significant drop in crash frequency. However, going slowly seems to at least reduce the crash frequency, but it is absolutely no guarantee -- it may crash even after an extremely simply small undo.

(I usually get anywhere from 1 to a dozen crashes a day, but since I try to avoid undo, especially several consecutive undo, the crash frequency has dropped somewhat.)

A crash may come on either undo or redo, with a slightly higher crash frequency for redo. Sometimes the crash comes after just a simple paste with no preceding undo/redo.

I have also experimented with changing font scheme to a very simple one, but it does not help.

My only tip would be: when you see that e.g a paste, or entered text, is inserted at the wrong place, try to save (or ignore that step), then chose Revert Document. Sometimes that trick works, sometimes not (and if not, it will crash). Sometimes it has helped by switching to another file and then back.

Also, if you want to undo just to inspect what the previous thing was, save before the undo, then, rather than redo, it may be slightly safer to Revert Document (but it is by no means any guarantee).

After a refactor, the window's fonts often look garbled. In this case, it has always helped to switch to another file and then back.

Hmm, is this Apple Quality? Steve's adherence to perfection?

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem, and the code will become complete nonsense - shortly afterwards, Xcode crashes. Happens on a daily basis.

Comment: Also getting same issue - Xcode 4.3.2 - crashes regularly after undoing!!!! This is NOT good!

Answer (score 1):

I have XCode 4.3.2 and I have exactly the same problem. This is a serious bug in XCode 4.3.2 especially because of the nonsense edit that it tossed around in various places in the code file that is being edited before XCode 4.3.2 crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Xcode 4.3.2, specifically the screen starts going garbled and if you are showing line numbers in your editor those will get messed up to then click somewhere else and *crash*.

Few quick helpful tips I have found:

1. Option-Command-S *before* you Command-Z (Save All) [in case it crashes you don't lose work]
2. If you do undo and you see it's messing up, open up another text file, then click back on the messed up file and it's now all better.

I sure hope Apple fixes this fast!

Comment: A lot of problems with XCode 4.x.
At least one crash per working day for me.
Seems it is the worst Apple's application.

Comment: Crashes about every 20 minutes for me.  It just crashed for about the 20th time today, so I consulted Google to see if someone found an answer.

Comment: I'm pleased to report that this issue has been solved in Xcode 4.5 for me.

Answer (score 0):

they fixed this partially in Xcode 4.3.1, it doesn't occur that often anymore

Comment: I'm experiencing problem with Xcode 4.5. When I undo, some of the last characters which I have written previously remains as is. They dont get removed. I think this has something to do with auto complete.

Answer (score 0):

Go slowly when using Undo/Redo. I've noticed that it crashes more when I'm hitting Command-Z many times quickly.

Try turning off the line numbers in Xcode preferences.  That seems to have improved things on my Mac.

Preferences -> "Text Editing" tab -> "Editing" subtab
   uncheck the "Line Numbers" button

From the look of the crash logs, it may be some kind of combination of undoing/redoing (editing) causing the view to scroll or the layout to change dramatically.

From my crash logs:

UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): -[DVTLayoutManager _fillLayoutHoleForCharacterRange:desiredNumberOfLines:isSoft:] *** attempted layout while textStorage is editing.  It is not valid to cause the layoutManager to do layout while the textStorage is editing (ie the textStorage has been sent a beginEditing message without a matching endEditing.)